# MATLAB - creating a database

Tags: matlab

I'm working on a project of image processing, where I have an image and I convert it like this:

```
a = imread ('4.jpg');  
b = rgb2gray (a);  
c = imadjust (b);  
d = im2bw (c);  
subplot (2,2,1), imshow (a),  
subplot (2,2,2), imshow (b),  
subplot (2,2,3), imshow (c),  
subplot (2,2,4), imshow (d)
```

The data of **a, b, c** and **d** show on the workspace. Which data can I use for the database and how could I store the features of that image into a database?

Answer (score 2):

I think it's easiest go for [mysql](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL) and use the [mym](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/linkexchange/links/1313-mysql-connector-mym) command. it can store matlab objects directly in a blob column.

If that is not an optin you could just store the feature you want in a mat file and submit that to the database of your choice.